# Navigate user from inside lightning component to new record page on mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, navigation

I want to be able to navigate a user from within a lightning component to the create new record page on the salesforce one app. I cant find any means of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is about navigating a user from within a lightning component to the create new record page on the salesforce one app. I would like to consider the below option. Anyways you can view your Lightning component as an app page only. Create an action to create a record of your desired object and add it to your home page.

**Add Quick Actions and Configure the Page**

> Quick actions allow users to quickly create and modify records. After
>   you add the actions, you activate the Lightning Page as an app, which
>   makes it available to mobile users.

- In the right sidebar, click Page to configure the app properties.
- At the bottom, click Select under Actions.
- Drag the Log a Call, New Case, New Lead, and New Task quick actions
  to the Selected list. Click OK to add the actions to your Lightning
  Page, and then click Save.
- The Actions property at the bottom of the inspector now shows the
  actions that you added.
- Activate the app, which automatically creates tabs and adds them to
  the Salesforce mobile app navigation.
- Click Activation....
- On the Page Settings tab, type Field Sales App for the App Name. It
  should already be defaulted in for you. Leave all other defaults as
  is.
- On the Mobile tab, click the Add page to app button and then drag the
  Field Sales App icon and place it below the Today icon.
- Click Save to activate.

[image]